# How to prevent xss script execution via url when using/testing with third party tool?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, cookies

Users/Testers in my website are able to execute scripts via url using [third party tool](http://portswigger.net/burp/)

So the tool is running and you enter 
`http://yoursite.com?q=nokia`188413544056">alert(document.cookie);16cd1a0b206

Then browser executes the alert in the url but not without tool.

I am using codeigniter/twig. Twig escaping does not work in case burpsuit tool is running.

However if normal scenario twig outputs the following escaped values and script in url does not execute.
`search?query=nokia188413544056%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(document.cookie);%3C/script%3E16cd1a0b206`

I am able to reproduce the same on IE after disabling the xss filter using internet option of IE.

However I have verified multiple times that we are striping tags and filtering all url parameters.

Can somebody guide me as what could be the reason, or is it even a valid case.

NOTE: I can provide more and more details out put of every step if needed.

Comment: It looks as though you are trying getting the values through GET vars. You could try XSS filter through the `$this->input->get("name", true);` <- noticed the second param, this will enable XSS filtering for the specified name/value pair. Alt you could enable global filtering in the config.php

Comment: @micb So I checked, and you are correct but in server side code, it is trying to get current url using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which we are printing on our twig templates by setting template variables. I want to know is there any codeigniter way of fetching this value(xss filtered).